# choosing between 2 actions in one controller with single view by checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got 2 actions in my controller, I want to choose which action to execute by checkbox in my razor view.

here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Person(string searchString)
    {
                                   
        var person = from p in db.Persons
            select p;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            person = person.Where(oo => oo.Name.ToUpper() == searchString);
        }
        
            return View(person);           
    }

    public ActionResult Job(string jobString)
    {
        var jobs = from j in db.Jobs
            select j;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(jobString))
        {
            jobs = jobs.Where(oo => oo.Name.ToUpper() == jobString);
        }
        return View(jobs);
    }
```

when I check a case I would like to execute the query search for this specific case

here is my view:

```
<div>
<form method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Person" value="Person" style="margin-left: 54px"/>Person
    </div>
    <div class="Job">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Job" value="Job" />Job
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="SearchString" style="margin-left: 90px;" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    }

</form>
```

Comment: why u added two forms ? html.beginform will create the form tag internally when executed

Comment: u r using nested forms which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Post to a single action method, then call one of your existing methods depending on the value of the checkbox.

```
public ActionResult Search(bool isJobSearch, string searchString)
{
    if (isJobSearch)
    {
        return Job(searchString);
    }
    else
    {
        return Person(searchString);
    }

}

private ActionResult Person(string searchString)
{
    // As your example
}

private ActionResult Job(string jobString)
{
    // As your example
}
```

Comment: actually he is creating two forms..whether his html is correct ? could you please check

Answer (score 0):

I am just correcting your html

Your html contains two form tags. I am not sure about the usage of form with in form tags. html.beginform will create internally another form tag when gets executed.So better one form tag will contain all elements to make a post.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Home"))
        {
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Person" value="Person" style="margin-left: 54px"/>Person
    </div>
    <div class="Job">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Job" value="Job" />Job
        </div>

            <p>
                <input type="text" name="SearchString" style="margin-left: 90px;" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }

    }
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection form)
{
//do some condition based on your needs
 if(form["SearchString"]=="Job")
   return RedirectToAction("Job");
else
return RedirectToAction("Person");
}

public ActionResult Person()
{

}

public ActionResult Job()
{

}
```

Comment: instead of entering Job in the search bar to redirect me to action i would like to do this with checkbox, when i select Job it redirect me to action Job. so i can search in database JOB from the search bar and the same thing with Person